# Design critique for sending SMS via external gateway

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, sms

We have a client-server based application that sends and receives SMS using an external gateway. 
I am thinking of redesigning/modifying the existing architecture to increase efficiency and performance.
Would welcome thoughts and suggestions around the same. Please note that during peak
hours approx. 3000 SMS are sent per hour from the client - server - gateway. 
The total amount of SMS sent per day could be anywhere between 8000 - 10,000

**Existing Architecture**

Send SMS

1. Client sends an SMS to the server, waits for unique smsid (generated by db) from server (open connection)
2. Server stores the sms in the database, sends the sms to the gateway.
3. Gateway sends the sms to the handset, returns unique receiptid to the server.
4. Server stores unique receiptid in the database
5. Server returns unique smsid(generated in step2) to the client

Steps 1 -5 is one request - response cycle.

Acknowledge SMS

1. The gateway sends the server the status of the message
2. The server updates the status of the message in the db from sent to delivered/failed/unknown etc.
3. The client polls the server regularly to receive the status for a message using the smsid previously received.
4. Client updates status on client side.

Database design

All the sms are stored in 1 single sms table in the database. Initially we had data , dating
back to around 2006, about 5 million records in the single table. We have now archived the data and only have
the current year's data in the table.

Cons
 - Long wait by client results in connection timed out errors at times, resulting in resending of same messages to the server. 
   As the server has no way of detecting that this is a duplicate message, it resends the message to the gateway, 
   resulting in duplicate sms to the customer.
 - Mutiple SELECT, UPDATE queries are performed on the sms table every second, sometimes putting considerable load on the db
   and failing of the system. Also no mechanism to archive data.

**New Architecture**

Send SMS

1. Client sends an SMS to the server, waits for unique smsid (generated by db) from server (open connection)
2. Server stores the sms in the database, returns unique smsid to the client.

Steps 1- 2 is one request-response cycle.

1. Separate process using cron to poll the database table regulary to retrieve sms
   and send to the gateway or could use java multithreading???
2. Gateway sends the sms to the handset, returns unique receiptid to the server.
3. Server stores unique receiptid in the database

Acknowledge SMS stays same as above

DB Design

1. Use Postgresql time/range partitioning to partition data based on date received, based on inheritance OR
2. Separate script to move data from table1 to table2 daily. Use union queries to join tables for reporting and retrieving data.

What is a better approach based on db performance?

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not convinced of the need to break this up into multiple tables.  You don't have bulk operations going on that are likely to make checking keys easier on a small table than a large one.  What is more likely to be helpful however in your case is the notion of partial indexes.  In this case you index current daily records only.

In this regard you might daily create a new index for the current date's records only and drop the previous index.  If you do this you will probably want to index the date too so you can create this partial index quickly.

I will edit this shortly with some performance notes once I have a chance to test.

UPDATE

After testing it looks like a plain date index won't be sufficient.  I think what you will have to do is something like add a current_index bool value attached, with a default of true.  Then you can index WHERE current_index = true and at the end of the day set these to false, thus dropping them off the index.

This will keep your queries fast, prevent adding new indexes to a table every day, and at the same time you get the benefit of a much smaller index.  This should give you the best of both worlds performance-wise.

ALSO this: *Separate process using cron to poll the database table regulary to retrieve sms and send to the gateway or could use java multithreading???*

take a look at LISTEN and NOTIFY in the Postgres docs.  Don't poll the db table.  Just poll on notification.  This will save you considerable overhead.  Don't rely on NOTIFY for the payload though since that is not secure.  Just use it as a "trigger" for your application to know that it should poll.

Basically what this does is sends a very light weight async notification to the server (you can do this in a trigger btw) and then your app gets to know it might be a good idea to poll.  the notification is sent when the nodifying transaction commits.

Comment: Great detailed answer, however there are bulk operations performed on the table. Insert - for inserting sms data in the table and Update when a notification is received from the gateway for a particular sms. During peak hours, a query with filters on the table takes about 10-15s which I believe is considerable time. I will take a look at LISTEN/NOTIFY and the partial indexes and get back.

Comment: Are those happening in bulk though?  How many rows are you inserting or updating at a time?

The key thing with partial indexes is that it buys you an ability to hit your large table using a small index, and the index doesn't necessarily grow as the table does.  It might be worth looking at what else could be optimized if the queries are taking this long as well.